# How to match only if a character occurs n times inside the match?

Tags: java, regex

https://regex101.com/r/gNNlKM/2

I want to match `START:test:test:test:asd:xxx:yyy:zzz:12345:END`, but, only if the `:` occurs 4 or more times.

In general, the following works: `(START.*?)\d+(:END)`
But how can I get `:{4,}` into?

The matching string may repeat itself multiple times. Like: `START:test:test:test:asd:xxx:yyy:zzz:12345:END...START:test:test:test:asd:xxx:yyy:zzz:12345:END...`
It's important that the `:{4,}` match is only applied inside each `START-END` token.

Sidenote: I'm using matching groups here as I lateron want to remove the digit in that special case. But that should not matter for the question how to get the n-times match into.

Comment: It seems you're looking for `START` followed by 4x `:[^:]*`, i.e. `:` followed by some non-`:` characters then `:END`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your regex like this,

```
(START(?:(?:(?!START)[^:])*:){3,})\d+(:END)
```

This will match only if the `:` is contained in the string exactly 4 times.

**Explanation:**

- `(START` - Starts the capturing group and matches `START` literally
- `(?:(?:(?!START)[^:])*:){3,})` - This matches some optional text and rejects the match if it sees literal `START` and followed by `:` where `{3,}` means three or more times.
- `\d+` - Matches one or more digits
- `(:END)` - Matches one more `:` and `END` literally and captures it in group2

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gNNlKM/5)**

Comment: As a side note: `(?:)` is a non capturing group and will not match a `:`, may be confusing in this specific context

Comment: @Lino: OP has written `(:END)` not `(?:END)` so that isn't a non-capture group. Also if you notice in his regex101 URL, he is referencing it back as `$2` hence that isn't a typo by OP but intends to capture in group2

Comment: I'm talking about `(?:[^:]*:)` which starts with `(?:` so this behaves like a *non-capturing-group*

Comment: @Lino: That is intentional. I deliberately made that group as non-capture by putting `?:` as OP doesn't have that in his original regex and I didn't want to introduce any extra groups because OP already has two intended groups which he is back referencing in his solution.

Comment: Thank you! One more question: I modified the sample so that it may repeat, and the {n} match should only count between each `START` and `END` tag individually.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I know, I just wanted to mention it, as it *could* be confusing for anyone *not knowing* about non capturing groups ;)

Comment: @membersound: Yes my regex is already working for that condition two. It gives you two matches for the string you mentioned. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/gNNlKM/4)

Comment: Your're right. But what if I would want to match `{4,}` 4 or more? I thought that would not make a difference, but does. Because, for example if I write `{13,}` in your last example, that should not produce any matches. But it does, as the quantifier somehow does not respect the word boundaries of each match?

Comment: @Lino: Oh ok :) yes one shouldn't confuse between `(:?` and `(:` as they look similar but are very different

Comment: @membersound: If you want to allow more than 4 colon, yes you just need to change `{4}` to `{4,}`

Comment: Yes I know, but try eg `{13,}` in your example. I'd expect no match in that case, but it does.

Comment: @membersound: Ok, you don't want to allow the match that spans across multiple START END tags right? Let me update my post to handle that as well.

Comment: @membersound: Done. Check now and let me know this is what indeed you wanted.

Comment: Glad to help brother :)