# How to replace a character inside a word boundary only if it occurs in that boundary at least n times?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to update a text column in a postgres table. The text in the column is only lower case and consists of utf-8 characters like [a-z0-9\u00DF-\u00F6\u00F8-\u017E\u1E00-\u1EFF\u03B1-\u03C9] plus '_' (underscore) plus ' ' (space). Space is the delimiter. I want to get rid of the underscore in a word boundary only if it occurs more than 3 times in that boundary. regexp_replace() based Solution is preferred, but it as also acceptable to solve it with other postgres specific function like string_to_array unnest array_to_string etc.

I found [How to match only if a character occurs n times inside the match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515814/how-to-match-only-if-a-character-occurs-n-times-inside-the-match) but could not adapt it for my Problem. Also experimented with string_to_array(), unnest(), array_to_string(), ARRAY(), CASE WHEN, regex_match in Combination, but i am stuck.

```
'photovoltaics renewable_energies flexible_low_cost_solar_cells colloidal_quantum_dots colloidal_quantum_dots_test1_test2'
```

should become

```
'photovoltaics renewable_energies flexible low cost solar cells colloidal_quantum_dots colloidal quantum dots test1 test2'
```

I need an UPDATE statement. How can i update following Table?

```
CREATE TABLE test_table AS
SELECT 1 as id, 'photovoltaics renewable_energies flexible_low_cost_solar_cells colloidal_quantum_dots colloidal_quantum_dots_test1_test2' as word
UNION
SELECT 2,'inter_cultural_fish_studies test contact_zones knowledge_from_below'
;
```

I could adapt the suggested solution from @Abelisto to following:

```
UPDATE test_table
SET word = (select string_agg(case when length(w)-length(translate(w,'_','')) >= 3 then translate(w,'_',' ') else w end, ' ') as w from unnest(string_to_array(word, ' ')) as w)
;
```

Comment: Without regexp: `select string_agg(case when length(w)-length(translate(w,'_','')) >= 3 then translate(w,'_',' ') else w end, ' ') as w from unnest(string_to_array('photovoltaics renewable_energies flexible_low_cost_solar_cells colloidal_quantum_dots colloidal_quantum_dots_test1_test2', ' ')) as w;`

Comment: The solution above [works](https://rextester.com/VOBC1005).

Comment: Because the suggested solution is not regex, I need an update statement see edit. The real Problem has more than 1 Million rows.

Comment: @Abelisto: After some trying i figured out, how to update: https://rextester.com/live/CTSR49140